# sp_msforeachdb in a stored procedure does not work well

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm facing strange behavior.

Here's how to reproduce: in an instance with multiple databases (SQL Server 2016 in my case), create that stored procedure (in `master` in my case):

```
create procedure dbo.Strange WITH EXECUTE AS owner
as
begin
    exec sp_MSforeachdb 'select''?''';
end;
```

Then call that stored procedure with:

```
Exec master.dbo.Strange
```

As you will see, it will only return data for some of the databases but not all (3 out of 11 in my case).

What is happening?

Comment: Can you tell us the names of the databases that work, and the ones that don't?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sp_MSforeachdb has lots of [known issues](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior).

If you follow the link, you'll get to a post by Aaron Bertrand that details them, and also provides an alternate solution.